# How to get the Top(base) parentWidget in QT?

Tags: qt, widget, parent

I am creating a software that must be accessible by parent to childrenWidget (or children of the children of the children....) and from the children to the parentWidget (or the parent of the parent of the parent ...).

For example :

```
QWidget_Principal --> WidgetApplications --> WidgetMenuBar --> PushButtonFullScreen.
```

The problem is that the way I can do this, is doing

```
this->parentWidget()->parentWidget()->parentWidget()->showFullScreen();
```

This there a simple way to do that ?

Thanks in Advance
And sorry for my very bad english.

Luis Da Costa

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use `QWidget * QWidget::window () const` to get window widget for your widget.

There is also `QWidgetList QApplication::topLevelWidgets () [static]` function, to get list of all top level widgets in your app...

Answer (score 6):

Another approach:

```
QWidget* topWidget = QApplication::topLevelAt(yourWidget->mapToGlobal(QPoint()));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write a global function:

```
QWidget* TopLevelParentWidget (QWidget* widget)
  {
  while (widget -> parentWidget() != Q_NULLPTR) widget = widget -> parentWidget() ;
  return widget ;
  }
```

Comment: Better use a dynamic cast to be sure, that you get a proper QWidget.

Answer (score 1):

Really simple python answer, call this within any child widget class of course:

```
top_widget = self
while top_widget.parentWidget(): top_widget = top_widget.parentWidget()
```